# How to call multiple functions using a file in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have multiple functions that I have to run. Both functions that I have run individually just fine, however when I try to run them simultaneously, only the first function runs correctly.

```
#Read file Emma.txt
fin = open('Emma.txt', 'r')


'''
Write a function wordNumbers which takes the file name and return
number of words in the file
'''

def wordNumbers(fin):

    #count the number of words.
    num_words = 0  #staring point for line
    for line in fin:
            words = line.split() #create a list of line
            num_words += len(words) #add each line legnth together
    print num_words #print total number of words

def lineNumbers(fin):

    #count the number of lines with a counter and while loop
    cnt = 0
    for line in fin:
            if cnt < line:
                    cnt += 1
    print cnt

wordNumbers(fin)

lineNumbers(fin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move to the beginning of file

```
wordNumbers(fin)
fin.seek(0) #  move to the beginning
lineNumbers(fin)
```

or reopen file

```
fin = open('Emma.txt', 'r')
wordNumbers(fin)
fin.close()

fin = open('Emma.txt', 'r')
lineNumbers(fin)
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first call, you've exhausted the input.  In order to do what you want, you need to seek back to the beginning before the second call.  Just add a seek call between the two as follows:

```
wordNumbers(fin)
fin.seek(0)
lineNumbers(fin)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you open a file and start reading from it, your position on file does not get reset until you close it. `fin = open('Emma.txt', 'r')` opens the file and then you use two functions to read from the file, while you should close it (or seek to the beginning using `fin.seek(0)`) after the first function call and open it again so that you read the file from the beginning again.